# Removing numerous annotations automatically in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, annotations

I have a package that contains lots of classes, each having lots of annotations. Is there any way to delete all the annotations automatically, rather than manually deleting them one by one?

I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA. I cannot use search and replace, because there are a lot of different annotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ has a feature called Structural Search and Replace. You could use it to find all annotations and replace with nothing. I have never really used this feature so can't offer you the exact search you need to use. The best I can offer is a link to the documentation for this feature. I am sure this feature can do what you want though:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/structural-search-and-replace.html